# How can I add a bottom margin to these bootstrap panels

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

[image]After each iteration of the panel-footer I would like a margin so every post isn't connected to the last. Solution doesn't have to be best practice, this is a project where any styling is extra credit.

erb:

```
<% if !user_signed_in? %>
<%= render 'devise/sessions/new' %>
<%= render 'devise/registrations/new' %>
<% else %>

<div class="panel panel-default center pull-right" >
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class='name'>
        <%= post.user.name %> shared:<br><br><br>
    </div>
    <%= post.body %>

    <%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put do %>
    Like
    <%= post.get_upvotes.size %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to dislike_post_path(post), method: :put do %>
    Dislike
    <%= post.get_downvotes.size %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <%= form_for @comment do |c| %>
        <%= c.text_area :body %>
        <%= c.hidden_field :post_id, :value => post.id %><br>
        <%= c.submit "comment" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Declaring a `margin` property rule on the containing element (`.panel`) should suffice, e.g: `.panel { margin-bottom: 20px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Hey not sure if you want to do it this way but you can wrap every post in a div tag with the same class name and give that class name a style of margin-bottom:

Answer (score 0):

If your example code generates an HTML `<form>` element, you can add margin to each one by using

```
.panel-footer form {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```